# Create dynamic DataSource in spring

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I would like to create data source object on the fly.
I won't be having data base details during compilation time, so I can't put this in either application.properties or hard code it in the code.

To put it simple, assume that I will get the details by calling a web service, by using those details I need to create data source(schema's will be same for all the urls).

```
@Configuration
public class DataBaseConfig {

    @Bean
    public DriverManagerDataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
DataBaseDetails details = someWebServiceCall;
        dataSource.setUrl(details.getURL());
        dataSource.setUsername(details.getUserName());
        dataSource.setPassword(details.getPassword());
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

This dataSource() would be called only during application start, is there any way to call to method dataSource for a session/request?

BR,
Kitty

Comment: Well, Spring does offer other scopes than singleton (prototype, session, request), so @Scope might be worth a look.

Comment: Hi Florian, Thanks for the reply. I tried using scope property but the problem is if I use "prototype" or "request"  it looks like spring creates an object which it  already created during application start(like cloning), it doesn't call the method again to create object.

Comment: Sounds strange, normally I would only expect Singleton beans to be created on startup, but not session or request beans...